# Magento2: How to update price with REST without changing category_ids attribute?

Tags: magento2, price, rest-api

Does someone know how to update the product price with REST API without changing the category_ids attribute.

If i perform a PUT /V1/products/{sku}
With body

```
{
 "product":
 {
 "price":"123"
 }
}
```

It removes the category_ids but looks like all other attributes are left unchanged.

Does anyone know a way to just update the price?

I looked through the document at http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ but could not find any other way to change the price on the product.

/Thomas

Comment: Try to pass `category_ids` as well, when updating price, does it work?

Comment: it does work fine when adding category_ids.
I was hoping there was a way out of the box to do this without having to know or fetch the category_ids before updating the price.

Comment: My quick fix was to create an index of my own with a few REST cals but its slow.
When i have time i need to find or make an api myself that can take an array of sku/price to do the price update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me.

I noticed that the `initialize` method in `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper` sets `category_ids` to an empty array if `category_ids` is not already present in the API request. So not providing `category_ids` in the API request has the same effect as setting it to an empty array.

My workaround, until a proper fix is (hopefully) released, is to extend the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` class and override the `initializeProductData` method, and remove `category_ids` altogether if it's empty. Your new `ProductRepository` class then needs to be the preferred `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` implementation.

The overriding method in my `ProductRepository` class looks like this:

```
protected function initializeProductData(array $productData, $createNew)
{
    $product = parent::initializeProductData($productData, $createNew);

    $categoryIds = $product->getData('category_ids');

    if ( empty($categoryIds) )
    {
        $product->unsetData('category_ids');
    }

    return $product;
}
```

And my di.xml has:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="My\Namespace\ProductRepository" />
```

If anyone have a nicer workaround/solution, please share.

(I have opened an issue about this, but have not received any feedback yet: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3354)

Comment: My quick n'dirty was to just get the category_ids for the product before updateing the product. Works ok on few products to update. Your solution is better. I'll try it if it doesn't get solved from magento in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

sending "null" as value for category_ids does the trick:
array("attributeCode" => "category_ids", "value" => null);